# How to make select query by string property name in lambda expression?

Tags: c#, select, lambda, expression

I would like to make a query by using lambda select,

Like below:

```
public class Foo{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string Surname {get;set;}
}

var list = new List<Foo>();
var temp = list.Select(x=> x("Name"),("Surname"));
```

The property name needs to be sent as a string,
I dont know how to use, I have given it for being a example.
is it possible?

Edit:

```
Foo list :
1  A B
2  C D
3  E F
4  G H
```

I don't know type of generic list,  I have property name such as "Name", "Surname"

I want to be like below:

```
Result :

A B
C D
E F
G H
```

Comment: This is unclear. Please give an sample input/desired output.

Comment: Try dynamic LINQ library. Hope that solves your problem. Please see the following link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deveshomar/dynamic-linq-library-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: Do you want to create a list of anonymous objects, with just Name or Surname, or you want to filter the list with a specific name and surname?

Comment: I have a just property names,  I don't know type of generic list,  I want to filter list by property names, not values.

Comment: I have displayed 2 examples, doing 2 different actions - one filtering and one creating a new list of anonymous objects having just 2 properties, Name and Surname.

Comment: question: `var list = new List<Foo>();` - means you know the type at compile time and you can directly access its property. I think you mean `var list = new List<T>();`?

Comment: I have given a sample, but it was unclear, actually var list = new List<T>() is right .

Answer (score 4):

The following code snippet shows 2 cases. One filtering on the list, and another creating a new list of anonymous objects, having just Name and Surname.

```
List<Foo> list = new List<Foo>();

var newList = list.Select(x=> new {  
                    AnyName1 = x.Name,
                    AnyName2 = x.Surname
                }); 

var filteredList = list.Select(x => x.Name == "FilteredName" && x.Surname == "FilteredSurname");

var filteredListByLinq = from cust in list
                             where cust.Name == "Name" && cust.Surname == "Surname"
                             select cust;

var filteredByUsingReflection = list.Select(c => c.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(c, null));
```

Comment: I don't said property value, I said property name, I don't know type of generic list, How can I use x.Name or x.Surname ?

Comment: So you want to filter x.Name right? In that case you can use any of the 2nd and 3rd options. Unless I misunderstood what you are asking for?

Comment: After editing your question, doesn't creating a list of anonymous objects solve your problem? You want to eliminate the Id, and create new properties but having values of name and surname right?

Comment: Yes, I cannot use anonymous object, because I don't know what the list contains properties, I just know property names,

Comment: I updated my answer, having a filtered list by using property string names. You have to use reflection...

Comment: I know that, how can I define a property for value, `var filteredByUsingReflection = list.Select(c => ????? = c.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(c, null))`;

Comment: He seems to need filtering, after all. But I'm not sure either. You know, requirements change all the time, this is the only constant in software development.

Comment: I also included a filtering by linq to sql in my answer, however it didn't answer the question it seems. The OP specifically wanted to use "Select" - but ah well I have to agree with you about requirements.

Comment: I misinterpreted your last comment, I apologize. I'm not sure I fully understood either, but it looks like you want anonymous types (again). I will post an answer with different options that could fit your needs.

Comment: @sinanakyazici did you manage back then? to help other users, pick the answer so that others can refer to it.

Answer (score 1):

### Interface

If you have access to the types in question, and if you always want to access the same properties, the best option is to make the types implement the same interface:

```
public interface INamable
{
  string Name { get; }
  string Surname { get; }
}

public class Foo : INamable
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

This will preserve type safety and enable queries like this one:

```
public void ExtractUsingInterface<T>(IEnumerable<T> list) where T : INamable
{
  var names = list.Select(o => new { Name = o.Name, Surname = o.Surname });

  foreach (var n in names)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(n.Name + " " + n.Surname);
  }
}
```

If, for some reason, you can't alter the original type, here are two more options.

### Reflection

The first one is reflection. This is Mez's answer, i'll just rephrase it with an anonymous type like in the previous solution (not sure what you need exactly):

```
public void ExtractUsingReflection<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)
{
  var names = list.Select(o => new
                               {
                                 Name = GetStringValue(o, "Name"),
                                 Surname = GetStringValue(o, "Surname")
                               });
  foreach (var n in names)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(n.Name + " " + n.Surname);
  }
}

private static string GetStringValue<T>(T obj, string propName)
{
  return obj.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(obj, null) as string;
}
```

### Dynamic

The second uses dynamic:

```
public void ExtractUsingDynamic(IEnumerable list)
{
  var dynamicList = list.Cast<dynamic>();
  var names = dynamicList.Select(d => new
                                      {
                                        Name = d.Name,
                                        Surname = d.Surname
                                      });
  foreach (var n in names)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(n.Name + " " + n.Surname);
  }
}
```

---

With that in place, the following code:

```
IEnumerable<INamable> list = new List<Foo>
                             {
                               new Foo() {Id = 1, Name = "FooName1", Surname = "FooSurname1"},
                               new Foo() {Id = 2, Name = "FooName2", Surname = "FooSurname2"}
                             };
ExtractUsingInterface(list);
// IEnumerable<object> list... will be fine for both solutions below
ExtractUsingReflection(list);
ExtractUsingDynamic(list);
```

will produce the expected output:

```
FooName1 FooSurname1
FooName2 FooSurname2
FooName1 FooSurname1
FooName2 FooSurname2
FooName1 FooSurname1
FooName2 FooSurname2
```

I'm sure you can fiddle with that and get to what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
var temp = list.Select(x => x.Name == "Name" && x.Surname == "Surname");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var temp = list.Select(x => new {Name = x.Name, Surname = x.Surname});
```