# How to get a Key of Func<Q, string> based on String Key

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, func, c#-6.0

I tried to write a generic method to get the sort key to perform `OrderBy` operation, but I failed in the following code.

```
public Func<Q, string> GetSortProperty<Q>(IQueryable<Q> data, string SortColumn) 
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sortColumn))
    {
        Func<Q, string> sort = i => i.GetType().GetProperty(sortColumn).GetValue(i, null);

        return sort;
    }

    return null;
}
```

I refereed the following Stack overflow questions

- [How to make select query by string property name in lambda expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26459953/how-to-make-select-query-by-string-property-name-in-lambda-expression)

Kindly assist me.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the `GetValue` declaration:

```
public virtual object GetValue(object obj, object[] index);
```

You can either change the type of the method from `Func<Q, string>` to `Func<Q, object>` :

```
public Func<Q, object> GetSortProperty<Q>(IQueryable<Q> data, string SortColumn)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SortColumn))
    {
        Func<Q, object> sort = i => i.GetType().GetProperty(SortColumn).GetValue(i, null);
        return sort;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Or cast it to `string`:

```
public Func<Q, string> GetSortProperty<Q>(IQueryable<Q> data, string SortColumn)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SortColumn))
    {
        Func<Q, string> sort = i => (string)i.GetType().GetProperty(SortColumn).GetValue(i, null);
        return sort;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Also if you are using C#6 I suggest change it like this to prevent `NullReferenceException`:

```
Func<Q, string> sort = i => (string)i.GetType().GetProperty(SortColumn)?.GetValue(i, null);
```